# Pinpoint exact cause of PHP out of memory error ( ...it was var_dump() )

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling, out-of-memory

I've been getting the out of memory error occasionally for a few months now on an app that has been in continuous development & has about 20 users so far.

It didn't seem to have any negative repurcussions I could detect, but finally I have found the culprit.

I don't know how but I had a default 404 error view into which strange code  had found its way, I'm not sure how I did that. This default 404 error view is called by the framework automatically if one uses findOrFail() and the db does not find a record. When a page was not available in my app (which is as it should be, as some content can be published/unpublished), this error view was triggering.

The weird code was:

```
<!-- <div><?php var_dump($exception); ?></div> -->
<div class="text">{{$exception->getMessage()}}</div>
```

Totally weird I know.

Firstly, the html comments, since it is a blade file, do not apply, so the var_dump was being called despite being 'commented out'.

So I replaced it with this:

```
{{ var_dump($exception) }}
```

and the out of memory error (and the 500 error in the browser) can be reliably reproduced.

Removing it, and the 404 view renders fine.

Replacing it with `{{ dd($exception) }}` works fine too - I get a render of the trace.

**So**, ***why does the var_dump line cause an out of memory error?***

**What should I do to investigate this further?**

I'm on Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This most likely happens because the content of the `$exception` variable is big. When you dump the variable, PHP will attempt to convert it to a string representation. This uses a lot of memory.

I don't see why you would need to output the entire exception object. You most likely just need the message (which you fetch by `$exception->getMessage()`. The rest is just backtrace and references to related objects and instances.

Comment: Thanks.  Totally agreed. I'm still interested in going deeper to investigate though, if possible, to improve debugging skill.  Want to nail it! :)    At times like this I think of Richard Feynman: "when i get on a problem, i just can't get off. i gotta do it!"  :)

Comment: You could take a look at the function [Exception::getTraceAsString](http://php.net/manual/en/exception.gettraceasstring.php) too

Comment: I did that - it gives me a trace but in a vastly more compact form than dd().  Then I checked the total file size of the page dd() returns, with the full stack trace.  Answer: 2MB.   Kind of would like to know why an out of memory error occurs (I'm at php's default 128MB memory limit).  Is it normal that php needs more than 128MB memory to generate a 2MB stack trace?   Or does that suggest there is something else weird going on?  Should I care?  Is it interesting to investigate? Much thanks.

Comment: I have not debugged that much in Laravel specifically, so I can only guess, BUT, what usually happens is that you dump the entire object where the stracktrace happened, which I guess is the entire Laravel object. This object most likely has references between components, Eloquent, Composer dependencies and so on. What usually happens is that these objects references each other back and forth, creating a kind of recursive tree. When you attempt to output this, PHP runs out of memory trying to resolve the recursion. You can attempt to just to `var_dump($this); die();` inside a view too.

Comment: Quote: "As far as your specific problem goes, many of Magento's objects contain reference to a large amount of information — and sometimes the references are circular. PHP's var_dump and print_r functions will blindly follow these circular references and attempt to print everything out.", From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21589314/921563

Comment: Thank you, that is a great answer, including the additional link you gave, and fully answers my question.